# Json Insert in Google BigQuery using cdata ado.net data providers

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, ado.net, google-bigquery

I am developing a console application in c#, to insert a set of records to the Google BigQuery tables. For insertion and selecting data am using cdata ado.net data providers. When inserting data with a for loop, it will insert the data but takes a long time to insert when the data range is over 100 000 rows.

So I decided to insert a json file containing rows of data in json format instead of executing a set of string query.

But I didn’t get a single idea how  to do that and where to start? Is there any other way to implement the same in C#-->BigQuery?

```
 private static DataTable GetDataTableTest(string Query)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            SqlDm SqlDM = new SqlDm(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLData"].ToString());
            SqlDM.StoredProcedureName = Query;
            dt = SqlDM.ExecuteDataTable();
            SqlDM = null;
            return dt;
        }
        private static void ADDToBigQueryTest()
        {
            string FileToInsert = "select Top 10 * from SalesTable";
            string InsertQuery = string.Empty;
            DataTable dt = GetDataTable(FileToInsert);
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    sbQuery.AppendLine(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                }

                InsertQuery = sbQuery.ToString();
            }


            using (GoogleBigQueryConnection BigCon = new GoogleBigQueryConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BigQuery"].ToString()))
            {

                GoogleBigQueryCommand BigCmd = new GoogleBigQueryCommand(InsertQuery, BigCon);
                BigCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n Inserted To BigQuery");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CData ADO.NET Provider for Google BigQuery supports INSERT INTO SELECT statements, which you can use to bulk insert data using a single request.

You do this by inserting rows into a local temporary table, then make your INSERT INTO SELECT call:

```
INSERT INTO publicdata:samples.github_nested#TEMP (repository.name, MyCustomField__c) VALUES ('New publicdata:samples.github_nested', '9000');
INSERT INTO publicdata:samples.github_nested#TEMP (repository.name, MyCustomField__c) VALUES ('New publicdata:samples.github_nested 2', '9001');
INSERT INTO publicdata:samples.github_nested#TEMP (repository.name, MyCustomField__c) VALUES ('New publicdata:samples.github_nested 3', '9002');
```

then execute:

```
INSERT INTO publicdata:samples.github_nested (repository.name, MyCustomField__c) SELECT repository.name, MyCustomField__c FROM publicdata:samples.github_nested#TEMP
```

Ref: http://cdn.cdata.com/help/DBA/ado/pg_insertselect.htm